# How to go about finding whether this limit exists: $\lim_{x \to 0} x [[\frac{1}{x}]]$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to solve few challenge questions on Real Analysis from Kaczor and Nowak's `Problems in Mathematical Analysis`, to become more proficient and stimulate thinking. I'd like someone to (a) verify if my proof is correct (b) is there a way to rigorously show that the limit does not exist?

*Note.* $[[x]]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

> Find the limits or state that they do not exist.

> Problem 1.1.1 (b) $\lim_{x \to 0}x\cdot[[\frac{1}{x}]]$

***Proof.***

Consider the sequences $a_n:=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=-\frac{1}{n}$. Both these sequences converge to zero.

The corresponding image sequences are,

\begin{align*}
(f(a_n)) &= \frac{1}{1}\cdot 1, \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2, \frac{1}{3}\cdot 3, \ldots \\
&= 1,1,1,1,1,\ldots
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
(f(b_n)) &= -\frac{1}{1}\cdot (-1), -\frac{1}{2} \cdot (-2), -\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-3), \ldots \\
&= 1,1,1,1,1,\ldots
\end{align*}

Also, consider the sequence $c_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. The sequence $(c_n)$ also converges to zero.

\begin{align*}
(f(c_n)) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\cdot [[\sqrt{1}]], \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot [[\sqrt{2}]], \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot [[\sqrt{3}]], \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} \cdot [[\sqrt{4}]], \ldots \\
&= 1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},1,\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}},1,\ldots
\end{align*}

Thus, the image sequence oscillates between $0$ and $1$ and is not convergent. This violates the definition of functional limits. We require that, for all sequences $(x_n)$ in the domain of the function $f$, such that $(x_n) \to a$, $x_n \ne a$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$, the image sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$. Then, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$. So, the above limit does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean by this violates the definition of functional limits?

Comment: In what sense does the sequence oscillate between $0$ and $1$? Are you claiming that $0$ is a limit point of the sequence? The sequence $1-\sin(n)/n$ also oscillates between $0$ and $1$ but its limit does equal $1$.

Comment: @GregMartin, I felt that as we go further into the image sequence $f(c_n)$ for instance, you have terms like $\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}}$, $\frac{4}{\sqrt{24}}$, $\frac{5}{\sqrt{35}}$, $\ldots$, I assumed that these terms get arbitrarily close to $0$. Calculating these values, however, I see, I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\frac 1x-1\lt [[\frac 1x]]\le 1/x $ for all $x\ne 0$
By Squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x[[\frac 1x]]=1=\lim_{x\to 0^-} x[[\frac 1x]]$

Answer (score 2):

I'll make a try to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x[[\frac{1}{x}]]=1$. For $x\not=0$ it is $[[\frac{1}{x}]]\leq \frac{1}{x}<[[\frac{1}{x}]]+1$ hence $\frac{1}{x}-1<[[\frac{1}{x}]]\leq \frac{1}{x}$ which means $1-x<x[[\frac{1}{x}]]\leq 1$ if $x>0$ and $1-x>x[[\frac{1}{x}]]\ge 1$ if $x<0$. So $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x[[\frac{1}{x}]]=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x[[\frac{1}{x}]]=\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}x[[\frac{1}{x}]]=1$